# parse nested json with volley

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

i want parse nested json like this json

> http://javatechig.com/?json=get_recent_posts&count=10

but i dont work with nested json before , i know parsing json object and array alone but i dont know nested json parsing . iwant get `title` in `posts` and get tumbnail url in tumbnail_images

i write some codes but i have a error

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    final String posts = response.getString("posts");

//                    ================================================ Json Array Request
                    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            String arrayResponse = "";

                            try {
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject post = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                                    String title = post.getString("title");
                                    arrayResponse += "title : " + title;

                                }

                            }
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //btnShow ClickListener
                            btnShowPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    txtShowPosts.setText(arrayResponse);
                                }
                            });



                        }
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "We have a problem in Array Request ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                jsonResponse = "";
                jsonResponse += "posts " + posts;
                );

            }

            catch(
            JSONException e
            )

            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "We have a problem ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

    ,new Response.ErrorListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "We have a problem in volley ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }

    );


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass your json String , you will get all title here.

```
public  ArrayList<String> getTitles(final JSONObject object){
    ArrayList<String> returnData = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        JSONArray postArray = object.getJSONArray("posts");
        for(int x=0;x<postArray.length();x++){
            returnData.add(postArray.getJSONObject(x).getString("title").toString());
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e){}
    return returnData;
}
```

**How :** In your JSON String you have to parse the title this way.

1. 1st convert the String to JSON.
2. Parse the array for post
3. then run a loop to get the child elements . (here you will find all titles)

Comment: thank you for your sulution but i need implemet that with volley library

Comment: pass the response JSONObject to the function. Volley can't parse JSON .

Comment: @majid , Appreciate with Upvote if it is useful :).